# Function to retrieve the temporary path of a file is failing for a given file size

Tags: php, size, temporary-files

I have a simple code as follows :

```
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

   echo $file_tmp;

   $file = new SplFileObject($file_tmp);

   echo filesize($file_tmp);
```

['file'] is the field of a html form in which the user selects the file to be treated in the action written in php.

```
<form method="POST" action="processCity.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <h2>Register list of cities from the file:</h2>
     <input type="file" name="file" required> <input type="submit" name="btnImport" value="Import">
</form>
```

It happens that when the file has more than
2097152 bytes (2.1 MB), the path is not returned in the $file_tmp variable. Does anyone understand this?
If the file size is less than or equal to the size given above, everything works fine.
¯_(ツ)_/¯
PHP 8.2.8
Ubuntu 20.04.6

I tried:
`$file = file($file_tmp);`
but it didn't work either. As before, only if the file size is <= 2097152 bytes (2.1 MB), the variable is populated with the path information of the file sent from the form with the POST method.

I looked for an answer here on the site and outside of it too but I didn't get an answer. I can't even imagine what it might be like to try something more on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to **upload_max_filesize** defined in **php.ini** file. And also a Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request defines as

**upload_max_filesize = 20M(default)** => change it as per you requirement.

**max_file_uploads = 20 (it is default limit)** => change it as per you requirement.

Comment: But the file size is only 2097152 bytes (2.1 MB). If I add 1 byte more, it already breaks the reading of the path.

Comment: Nimesh, I tried. The default was 2M in the php.ini file installed on my machine. I set up to 20M and 80M to post_max_size, but still not working after I reboot the server. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: @miguel Upload a file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check its output, make sure the changes to your php ini have been applied. You can also see in the info what php.ini file has been loaded. You might find it is using a different php.ini (in a different folder) than what you expect.

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit bang on! There was another php.ini file in another folder (/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini ) instead of (/etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini) where I was changing it. Why? What a mess! I don't know, whatever, you all saved me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that solved it. The 'cli' (command line interface) one is used when you run php directly from the commandline, the 'apache' one is used when php is used by apache webserver (serving pages).